# Promise chain with an asynchronous operation not executing in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, es6-promise, node-mysql

I have found other people asking about this topic but I haven't been able to get my promise chain to execute in order.

Here is a basic reproduction of what is happening:

```
function firstMethod(){

    dbHelper.executeQuery(queryParameters).then(result => {

        if (result === whatIAmExpecting) {

            return dbHelper.doDbOperation(secondQueryParameters)}

        else {

            throw new Error('An error occurred')

        }})

        .then(doFinalOperation())
        .catch(error => {

        })
}
```

In the above code doFinalOperation() is called before the then function after executeQuery() is called.

Here is the implementation of executeQuery():

```
function executeQuery(parameter) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const queryToExecute = `SELECT * FROM parameter`

        return mySqlConnection.query(queryToExecute).then((result) => {

            resolve(result)

        }).catch(error => {

            reject(error)
        })
    })
```

And here is the implementation of of the  mySqlConnection.query method:

```
function query(queryString){

 return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {

  initConnection()

  connection.connect()

    require('bluebird').promisifyAll(connection)

     return connection.queryAsync(queryString).then(function(results) {

        connection.end();

        resolve(results)

        }).catch(error => {

                reject(error)
            })
      })
```

It seems like I have incorrectly implemented the executeQuery() method. The database operation in the mySqlConnection.query is asychronous and I can see that's where the chain of promises stops happening in the expected order.

**My question in a nutshell:** How do I make the my chain of promises execute in order, and how I do stop a then() method from being executed before the previous Promise has called resolve() or reject()?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have no control over which request will be served first, so unless you make them sequentially you can't say in which order they will complete. I wonder why you would want them to complete in a particular order though. As long as you don't have data dependencies, parallel execution is the most time-efficient strategy. But surely you have your reasons.

Comment: To make things sequential you have to launch the next request only after the previous promise is fulfilled (or failed). This will be pretty slow though, and will defeat the purpose of promises in the first place (a plain sequential code would do exactly the same job).

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The `doFinalOperation()` method should only be called if the other methods successfully complete so it is dependent upon the previous operations so the methods do have to be called sequentially. Why would making them sequential defeat the purpose of promises though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`then` expects a function, but you have accidentally executed it, instead of passing it. Change:

```
 then(doFinalOperation())
```

with:

```
 then(doFinalOperation)
```

Now it will be the promise implementation that invokes it (at the proper time), not "you".

If your function needs arguments to be passed, then you can either

(1) Use `bind`:

```
 then(doFinalOperation.bind(null, parameterOne, parameterTwo, parameterThree))
```

(2) Use a function expression

```
 then(_ => doFinalOperation(parameterOne, parameterTwo, parameterThree))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution can solve the issue but as the actual `doFinalOperation()` requires parameters it has to be called like `doFinalOperation(parameterOne, parameterTwo, parameterThree)` so I can't pass it without calling it. But, if I implement it like: `then( _ => {doFinalOperation(parameterOne, parameterTwo, parameterThree)})` then it does work. I already marked the other answer as correct but I up-voted your answer. This solution is also potentially better as it requires less nesting

Comment: You can use `bind` to bind your arguments. See update.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's useful to know

Comment: NB: the other answer still has `doFinalOperation` called too soon: it does not wait for the `doDbOperation` to resolve first.

Comment: You're right. I've marked this answer as correct. Thanks for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Both your `.then()` methods get called on the first async operation...
Should be something like this:

```
function firstMethod(){
   dbHelper.executeQuery(queryParameters).then(expectedResult => {
      if (expectedResult === whatIAmExpecting) {
         return dbHelper.doDbOperation(secondQueryParameters)}
            .then(doFinalOperation())
            .catch(error => {
            };
      }
      else {
         throw new Error('An error occurred')
      }})
      .catch(error => {
      });
}
```

Comment: Should `doFinalOperation()` be `doFinalOperation`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution can solve the issue

Comment: I had to mark the other answer as correct because by calling the doFinalOperation() method in the then() method the doFinalOperation() method still executed before all of the previous operations had been completed. I appreciate your help though. Cheers